# CSS Specificity - Conflicts between CSS selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I have a question regarding the following pseudo-class selector.
Even with `!important`, the text under this `li:first-child` is not showing blue.

p has Selector Specificity: (0, 0, 1)
li:first-child has Selector Specificity: (0, 1, 1)

I am expecting the xyz to be blue but it is red. Unless comment out CSS for p (red color).

[image]

```css
p {
  color: red;
}

li:first-child {
  color: blue !important;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<p>abc</p>
<aside>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>xyz</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

After reviewing the answer, the new code is good:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
      p {
        color: red;
      }
      li:first-child p {
        color: blue;
        list-style: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>abc</p>
    <ul>
      <li><p>xyz</p></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `li:first-child` makes the color of the `<li>` blue, but the `<p>` is still red.

`li:first-child` selects the li that *is* a first child, not the first child *of* the li.

Answer (score 0):

```css
p {
  color: red;
}

li:first-child p {
  color: blue !important;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<p>abc</p>
<aside>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>xyz</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).